# Splitting out SQL columns based on specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a table like below.

Prospects:

```
+----------------+---------------+----------------+  
| Account NO   | Contact            | LastName |    
+----------------+---------------+----------------+  
| 1233         | john bar           |  bar        |  
| 2341324      | rich & mary johns  |  johns      |  
| 21343        | wayne & elise smith|  smith      |  
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to create a view that will pull out the names 'John, rich, and wayne" into a column called first name, and then grab the names after the `'&'` and put them in a column called Spouse only if there is a `'&'`. Finally i would create a last name column.

So spouse column would contain Mary and elise and be `NULL` for John Bar.

Right now I am using the below, which pulls out the first name and last name no problem. It also gets rid of the '&' but I am having issues separating the spouse name from the last name in the 'Spouse' Column

```
SELECT  
    ACCOUNTNO,  
    SUBSTRING(Contact, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Contact)) AS [First],
    SUBSTRING(Contact, CHARINDEX('&', Contact) + 1, LEN(Contact)) AS [Spouse],  
    LASTNAME as Lastname  
FROM Prospects
```

My return value for spouse is 'mary johns' and 'elise smith'. I am looking to get rid of the last name.

Comment: You already have a column LastName, why do you want to create a new one?

Comment: I am not looking to create a new last name column, I am looking to create a spouse column with the correct output. If you are referring to 'LASTNAME' as LastName that is something I can remove.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using: MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle...? Please add the relevant tag your question.

Comment: I am using SQLServer, tag is added. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

With replace() and substring():

```
select 
  accountno AS [AccountNo],
  substring(contact, 1, charindex(' ', contact) - 1) AS [First],
  case 
    when contact like '% & %' then
      replace(
        replace(contact, ' ' + lastname, ''), 
        substring(contact, 1, charindex(' ', contact) + 2), '') 
    else ''
  end AS [Spouse],
  lastname AS [LastName]
from prospects
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a299a7c547048b266086538400a8ae0).
Results:

```
 AccountNo | First | Spouse | LastName
 --------: | :---- | :----- | :-------
      1233 | john  |        | bar     
   2341324 | rich  | mary   | johns   
     21343 | wayne | elise  | smith
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to extract the first and last names, and `SUBSTRING` to get the optional spouse name, as follows:

```
SELECT  
    ACCOUNTNO,
    Contact,
    LEFT(Contact, CHARINDEX(' ', Contact) - 1) as First,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' & ', Contact) > 0
        THEN SUBSTRING(
            Contact, 
            CHARINDEX(' & ', Contact) + 3, 
            LEN(Contact) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact)) - CHARINDEX(' ', Contact) - 2
        )
    END AS Spouse,
    RIGHT(Contact, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact)) - 1) AS Lastname
FROM Prospects
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=268a5feed02e3e90f0f96311c7d0de3a)**:

```
ACCOUNTNO | Contact             | First | Spouse | Lastname
--------: | :------------------ | :---- | :----- | :-------
     1233 | john bar            | john  | null   | bar     
    21343 | wayne & elise smith | wayne | elise  | smith   
  2341324 | rich & mary johns   | rich  | mary   | johns
```